# Force VBA to display currently-selected cells when prompting user to select a range with Inputbox in Excel

Tags: excel, vba, inputbox

I know that I can use Inputbox to prompt the user to select a range

```
Set rng = Application.InputBox( _
  Title:="Number Format Rule From Cell", _
  Prompt:="Select a cell to pull in your number format rule", _
  Type:=8)
```

However when this code is executed, the inputbox will initially be empty

[image: Empty Inputbox]

How can I make it so that this box will display the currenty-selected cells?

Answer (score 2):

We can make use of the Default property of the Inputbox method like this:

```
Set RangeDest = Application.InputBox("Select range to paste onto ", "Obtain Range Object", Selection.Address, Type:=8)
```

[image]

Comment: To match OP's style: 'Default:=Selection.Address'.